# Returning Column Header for first occurence of cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, vlookup

My raw data set is pretty straightforward.

- My columns run `A-AM` with a column header for each.
- There are no row labels.
- The data consists of serial numbers of varying lengths, from two to seven digits.

A serial number in one column will likely be repeated in several other columns. There are over one million entries with over seventy thousand unique serial numbers.

I ordered all of the serial numbers on a separate sheet in a `column A`.

What I would like is to populate `column B` with the corresponding column header of the serial numbers first occurrence in the array, from left to right. If possible, I'd like to have a similar formula in `column C` that shows the column header for the cell's last occurrence in the array (right to left).

The raw data looks like this. (`A1:H7`)

**`1974   1975   1976    1977    1978   1979    1980    1981`**

`20     160     240      278     436   360    1696    1772`

`23     162     242      279     438   404    1698    1774`

`24     168     244      280     440   760    1700    1782`

`26     170     246      282     444   1620   1702    1784`

`28     188     248      283     449   1622   1706    1786`

`30     190     250      284     450   1624   1708    1788`

Comment: Can you an example of some formulae or datatable(A1:H7 for example) . It will make it easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I tried posting a better looking sample of the data, but failed. Any tips on that for the future would be helpful so I can ask quality questions.

Comment: pnuts, you may be right about VBA. I changed the tag and will post my first attempt. I just felt like there should be a simple formulaic solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: @Joel Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub getOccurs()

    Dim findVal As String

    Dim wsUniqueSN As Worksheet
    Dim rngUniqueSN As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range

    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngLastCell As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Dim rngFirstFound As Range
    Dim rngLastFound As Range

    Const notFound As String = "[ VALUE NOT FOUND!! ]"

    Set wsUniqueSN = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UniqueSN")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Set rngUniqueSN = wsUniqueSN.Range("A1", wsUniqueSN.Range("A" & wsUniqueSN.Columns.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set rngLastCell = wsTarget.Range("H" & wsTarget.Rows.Count)
    'Use this if all columns contain the same number of rows to speed up the operation
    'Set rngLastCell = wsTarget.Range("H" & wsTarget.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("A2", rngLastCell)

    For Each xlCell In rngUniqueSN

        findVal = xlCell.Value

        Set rngFirstFound = rngTarget.Find(What:=findVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, After:=rngLastCell)

            Set rngLastFound = rngTarget.Find(What:=findVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                                After:=rngLastCell, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not rngFirstFound Is Nothing Then
            xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = wsTarget.Cells(1, rngFirstFound.Column).Value
        Else
            xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = notFound
        End If

        If Not rngLastFound Is Nothing Then
            xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = wsTarget.Cells(1, rngLastFound.Column).Value
        Else
            xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = notFound
        End If

    Next xlCell

    MsgBox "Operation complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Call your Data worksheet "Data" and the sheet containing Unique Serial Numbers UniqueSN, making sure that the SN are in column A. 
The macro will loop through the SN used range and look for the corresponding entries both in forward and in reverse order, writing the respective column headers in columns B and C.